# Cannot connect to Interactive Brokers Trading Workstation via Python API

Tags: networking, localhost, port, interactive-brokers

I'm trying to connect to the Interactive Broker's TWS via the Python API using this simple code:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper


class App(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)


# Establish API connection
# app.connect(ipAddress, portNumber, clientId)
app = App()
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 999)
app.run()
```

But when I run it I get:

```
ERROR -1 502 Couldn't connect to TWS. Confirm that "Enable ActiveX and Socket EClients" 
is enabled and connection port is the same as "Socket Port" on the 
TWS "Edit->Global Configuration...->API->Settings" menu. Live Trading ports: 
TWS: 7496; IB Gateway: 4001. Simulated Trading ports for new installations 
of version 954.1 or newer:  TWS: 7497; IB Gateway: 4002
```

Even though I have "Enable ActiveX and Socket EClients" and the port set at 7497:

[image: Image of My Global Configuration]

I'm not sure why I can't connect via localhost as when I try running the same code on another computer it can connect perfectly fine. Could this possibly be specific to my computer? And what can I do to resolve it?

Comment: change localhost ip (127,0.0.1) to the real ip address, it might be 192.168.0.1, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The same connection issue appears when using WSL2 on a Windows machine.
I tried running the script from the Windows version of Python which worked fine.
Another solution is to specify IP from a local network in your code and TWS trusted IPs list. (information found [here](https://groups.io/g/insync/topic/88418534#7472))

Under WSL using ib_insync (the syntax and error are similar for native API):

[image]

IB Gateway settings:

[image]